# How to disable https redirect on a single page with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to disable https on a page on my site which also have a dynamic sub pages. For example http://example.com/page/dynamic/section.

I have try below htacess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/page/* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But still get stuck and it redirecting to https please any one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to disable https on a page on my site which also have a dynamic sub pages. For example `http://example.com/page/dynamic/section`:

You may use this .htaccess code:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# add www if missing to all the URIs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# turn on https except for a specific URI
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/page[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# force http for a specific page:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^page(/|$) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice rules, what is `%{HTTPS}s` in this, will be grateful if you could explain it a bit, temp comment.

Comment: That is a special condition to keep same scheme (http or https) in redirect URL. If `HTTPS` is already there in URL then `s` will be matched in `%1` otherwise `%1` will be empty.

Comment: Thank you please I want you to note that /dynamic/section are randomly generated base on content user request. I may not know the exact this I why I call it Dynamic.

Comment: If you don't know what the actual URI is then how do you think you can build a rule that enforce `http://` for those URLs?

Comment: Let say like this I want this page to be only http only http://example.com/page but under this page 2 dynamic param might be passed to text the content user request http://example.com/page/param1/param2

Comment: Sure, that can be done. Try my updated answer